# Performance, is it better to use Observable collection or INotifyPropertyChange?

Tags: c#, performance, c#-4.0

I have to make some programs in c# and in order to perform IO between programs i have to use, or property using `INotifyPropertyChange`(on a `List<>`) or `ObservableCollection<>`.

I'd like to know which one is the better to perform IO operation between c# programs.

Thank you for reading

Comment: Why not just write some code using the one that is best for your design?  By thinking about this sort of thing now, you're not concentrating on the problem at hand.

Comment: Well, both have the same design it's a list of String or an oobservable collection of string, my question isn't about design but performance

Comment: @user2417992 do a benchmark then :)

Comment: I'd like to but i can't, i am making some kind of plugin for a program and i need the content of list for example string, and i try to see if the plugin work but i don't the source of the second program ..

Comment: @user2417992 you dont need the plugin to do a benchmark. Just create a little program the stresstests both senarios, and then compare them.

Comment: create fake data for your tests. But if the list length max is, say, 1000, you shouldn't be nervous.

Comment: Okay i'm going to try that thanks =)

Comment: I had to build a software with 200.000 -> 1.000.000 items in the list, and for performance i had to use an array. I Build a new array on each refresh, and performances are very good. The soft collapsed around 100.000 with an Observable Collection. If your collection is that big, don't forget to watch for Virtualisation of your display control (expl:ListView).

Comment: ObservableCollection already implements INotifyPropertyChanged. So if you are binding your list to UI, use ObservableCollection. If it is a Class to UI binding you can implement INotifyPropertyChanged over your class.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Based on the criteria you list in the question & comments, you're best off with an ObservableCollection.

The INotifyPropertyChanged interface exists to tell you just that - a property changed. When you're talking about a list, the properties will be things like Count and Item[]. This means that, effectively, all you're actually being told is "the contents of the list have changed" but not any details as to what that change actually was. Without any such information, all your control can really do is redraw itself completely based on the current state of the collection.

With ObservableCollection, however, you get told when an item is added (and what that item was and where it was added) and when an item is removed (and what that item was and where it used to be). This is enough information for your UI control to only have to redraw *what has actually changed*, which is far more efficient than redrawing the entire thing. This is why ObservableCollection was invented - use it!

Comment: When the item count goes above 100.000, the performances and memory footprint of an ObservableCollection will make any computer collapse. In that case, go for an array that you re-create on each change. Not 'MVVM' text-book, but blazing fast (more than 30 times faster for the specific benchmarks i did for my application).

Answer (score 4):

Take a note that [ObservableCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx)  inherits both INotifyCollectionChanged, and INotifyPropertyChanged.

```
[SerializableAttribute]
public class ObservableCollection<T> : Collection<T>, 
    INotifyCollectionChanged, INotifyPropertyChanged
```

See documentation from link above:

> In many cases the data that you work with is a collection of objects. For example, a common scenario in data binding is to use an ItemsControl such as a ListBox, ListView, or TreeView to display a collection of records.
>   You can enumerate over any collection that implements the IEnumerable interface. However, to set up dynamic bindings so that insertions or deletions in the collection update the UI automatically, the collection must implement the **INotifyCollectionChanged** interface. This interface exposes the **CollectionChanged** event, an event that should be raised whenever the underlying collection changes.
>
> WPF provides the **ObservableCollection class**, which is a built-in implementation of a data collection that implements the **INotifyCollectionChanged** interface.
>   Before implementing your own collection, consider using **ObservableCollection** or one of the existing collection classes, such as List, Collection, and BindingList, among many others. If you have an advanced scenario and want to implement your own collection, consider using IList, which provides a non-generic collection of objects that can be individually accessed by index. Implementing IList provides the best performance with the data binding engine.

Comment: Thank you =) i understand better some things now !

Answer (score 1):

**INotifyPropertyChanged** is used to notify the UI when the bounded property value or collection is changed. Whereas **ObservableCollection** is used to notify the UI when the bound collection is modified(Ex adding or removing object from the collection) It cant notify the UI if the property value in one of the collection object is changed.

Comment: Well as i can use a notifyPropertychange on a list they actually do the same thing

Comment: Well there is a different, If you use ObservableCollection it will notify the UI only if there is any changes to the collection (Ex: Adding new object or removing an object) But it cant notify if a property is changed in one of the object in collection.

Comment: Once again in my case it is the same thing, i am only getting list of strings(sometimes object containing many strings) but once they are in the list they can't change(but they can be removed) so it's the same thing.

Comment: raising INotifyPrCh on list which content changed will **NOT** update the UI, since the list itself did not change. Only if you create a new list it will change.

Answer (score 1):

These two alternatives do not do the same thing.  You are choosing between these two options:

1. a list property implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged`, where you throw the event every time the list is modified
2. a property of type `ObservableCollection`

With option 1, when you modify the list, an event is raised that says "the entire list has changed."  If you have a UI element bound to this list (say, a `ListBox`), the *entire* element will have to be redrawn, because it has to assume that the entire list has been changed (that is: it may no longer be the same list!).

With option 2, you are raising specific events about individual items that were added or removed in the list.  If you have a UI element bound to this list, it can respond by only modifying the UI that is relevant for these elements.

Consider the example where you remove an item from your list, and the list is bound to a WPF `ListBox` control.  With option 1, the entire content of the list is re-created.  With option 2, the removed item's control is removed but the rest of the list is left intact.

It should be clear from this example that the `ObservableCollection` - because it supports an event that is *specific* to what you are doing - will be more efficient in many cases.  That said, unless you have a huge amount of data in the collection or a very complex UI, the performance gain will be negligible.  Further, if you're making large modifications to your list, you may well find that it's faster to refresh the whole list.

Ultimately, no performance question can be answered accurately on StackOverflow without repeating the mantra: *profile your code, and make a decision based on the results.*